# What is the Italian equivalent of The Chicago Manual of Style?

Tags: orthography, punctuation, resources, writing, typography

*The Chicago Manual of Style* is one of the oldest and most comprehensive English style guides. It's well-respected and widely used in the publishing industry, covering the areas of copy editing, grammar and typesetting.

What would be the closest equivalent for Italian?

Bonus points if you can offer some insider info on what other sources typographers and editors think highly of.

Also, what are some book, magazine or journal publishers that are known to pay special attention to good typography and typesetting?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure there is a single Italian style guide accepted or used by all or most in the publishing industry (I am not sure this is the case for English either, at least if we consider together AmE and BrE). Most publishers have their own *Norme editoriali*, especially for such stuff as punctuation, dialogues, several types of inverted commas, abbreviations, use of foreign words, upper and lower cases, and also actual linguistic issues.
A well-thought, publicly available example of such norms is the [*libro di stile* of the magazine *Internazionale*](http://www.internazionale.it/dalla_redazione/2015/06/25/libro-stile-internazionale).

For what concerns language in itself, there are several excellent grammars and reference works: one of the most complete and well-regarded is perhaps *Italiano* by Luca Serianni (with Alberto Castelvecchi) published both by UTET and Garzanti (and mentioned as a reference by the above-mentioned *Internazionale*). In everyday publishing practice, resorting to Serianni is often useful to settle disagreements.

As regards editing and typesetting (and conventions about everything from internal divisions of the text to relevant ISO norms), a good and widespread reference is *Il nuovo manuale di stile* by Roberto Lesina, published by Zanichelli.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding grammar and style, there is a well reputed institution, named [*Accademia della Crusca*](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/&ved=0ahUKEwj5nr2DtanNAhUExRQKHRNAAUYQFggcMAA&usg=AFQjCNG5uOkt0pKz5E7JyLGFrAD445LHNQ&sig2=S7ClMX6YSxyCr12bF5eMkA), 
which serves as main reference on the Italian language.

They have a number of [publications](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/pubblicazioni/collane) which could be what you look for.